# SQL Server xml exist() method uses multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I want to use multiple conditions in SQL Server xml exist() method, however the result are different between single exist() with xmlquery logical expression and multiple exist() with t-sql logical expression. And the reason I want to use Query 1 is the performance consideration since I have millions rows in xml table.

Here is an example:

```
declare @xmltab table (A xml)
insert into @xmltab 
values ('<A>1</A>'),('<A>1</A><B>1</B>'),('<A>1</A><B>1</B><C>1</C>')
```

Query 1

```
select A from @xmltab
where A.exist('B or C') = 1

-- return 3 rows
```

Query 2

```
select A from @xmltab
where A.exist('B') = 1 or A.exist('C') = 1

-- return 2 rows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct XPath/XQuery expression to match either `<A>` or `<B>` would be (output should be 2 rows, see the linked demo below) :

```
select A from @xmltab
where A.exist('*[self::B or self::C]') = 1
```

**<kbd>[`rextester demo`](http://rextester.com/GYIG94603)</kbd>**